# If "I did Exercise 1 but not 2" is correct, then why is "The exercise I did was 1 but not 2" not correct?

Tags: difference, negation, coordination

a conclusion from one of threads on [forum.wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/1-but-not-2-vs-not-2-but-1.3683932/):

> **(1a)** *I did Exercise 1, not 2*. — correct
> **(1b)** *I did Exercise 1 **but** not 2*. — correct
> **(2a)** *The exercise I did was 1, not 2*. — correct
> **(2b)** *The exercise I did was 1 **but** not 2*. — incorrect
> **(2c)** *The exercise I did was 1 **and** not 2*. — correct

(1b) and (2b) have the same construction "X but not Y".
But why is (2b) incorrect whereas (1b) is correct?
What distinguishes them?

Answer (score 2):

"Incorrect" and "correct," when we're talking about usage, are overly strict words. We're more *likely* to say 2c than 2b, but does that make 2b *wrong*? No rule has been broken, it's just a meaning that we're unlikely to have. Let's plug different words into the same structure:

> Penguins are birds but not ones that fly.

"But" makes sense because most birds fly; the first half of the sentence sets up an expectation that the second half stands against, so "but" is a good linking word.

In your example 1b, "I did Exercise 1 but not 2," the "but" also makes sense because the first half of the sentence is about your accomplishment and the second half is about the opposite, what you didn't do. It's a bit of an opposite; if you expanded it into a dialog it might go like "I did Exercise 1." "Yay!" "I didn't do 2." "Boo!"

The examples numbered "2" change the subject of the sentence and so change the meaning a bit. In 1a and 1b, the subject is "I"; we're talking about me. In the 2s, the subject is "the exercise I did." We're talking about the exercise. All of the "not 2" phrases change from "what I didn't do" to "what the completed exercise was not." The completed exercise "had the property of being 1." "Not being 2" is also a property it had. If it "was 1," there's no reason to think it was also 2; in fact, as soon as we say it was 1, the reasonable assumption is that it's not 2. So clarifying that it's "not 2" is extra information, not contradicting information. So "and" makes more sense than "but."

Comment: Can I say "_I did Exercise 1 and not 2_"? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii Sure; it's extra information. You don't *have* to emphasize it being opposite. "And" works better here than it would in my penguin example!